# how to open hyperlink page from a client side

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Yhis is what I want to do:

```
<a href="javascript:sayHello('an nyung')"> click here </a>
```

this code is in a server side.

And I want to call this link from a client side by using ruby.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Question is not clear. What does "call this link" mean? Do you want to use Ruby to generate a link that looks like that or do you want to trigger a click event on a link? Also, you should avoid the `javascript:` pseudo-protocol and use an event handler instead.

Comment: Yes, this is very unclear. Are you saying that you have a method server-side that is written in Ruby called `sayHello`?

Comment: dear jimmy, 

I mean I wanna trigger the link or the javascript function of a server side by using my script in a client side. :)

thanks you for your concerns.

Answer (score 0):

You probably mean to use the link_to_remote method:

```
<%= link_to_remote('click here', say_hello_path('an nyung')) %>
```

This will make a call to the server when the link is clicked by the user.

Comment: but, the server side code isn't my code. it is just a general website like amazon. In this case, is this code also available? the thing I want to do is just to call the link(javascript function). ;) thanks .

Comment: Sounds like you need to implement something in JavaScript. You should re-post a question with a specific example of what you need to trigger.